# Application's exit status is different than when application run by shell script

Tags: eclipse, bash, shell

I have a confusion over the exit code of the application and the bash return value. For an eclipse application, a command line interface ran using eclipse returns the exit code as 1 (which is expected upon error). but when I run same command line using shell file and checks the return value with "echo $?" it always returns value as 0.

Application launched in command line mode in Eclipse :

[image]

Shell script :

command ="toolCli.exe -application arguments"

$command

echo $?

Output I get here is always 0, what's exactly the difference here?

Comment: Then what *is* your command?

Comment: @yaccits a tool's command line interface command which invokes toolsCli.exe. The format of the command is toolsCli.exe -application <arguments>

Comment: I think it's a tokenization issue. What do you get with `eval "$command"`? And toolsCli.exe might eclipse the original exit value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ com="echoo hi"
$ $com
No command 'echoo' found, did you mean:
 Command 'echo' from package 'coreutils' (main)
echoo: command not found
$ echo $?
127
```

As you can see the exit value does work, I believe your issue might be to do with the environment, as in the eclipse environment be different from your bash environment?

From the java path, it looks like you have a 64 bit windows env and that eclipse might be using the standard windows command line, so I'm interested in how you are expecting it to behave as a bash env?

So maybe run the command under a windows command line and see if it fails, compare the java setup in both environments.